# Rails 3.1: Determine if asset exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Is there a built-in way to determine if an asset exists without resorting to `File.exists?(File.join(Rails.root, "foo", "bar", "baz"))` and that looks through the asset paths.

My app goes and fetches images from a remote server on a Resque queue; until we have the image downloaded I want to serve a placeholder image.  Currently I'm using `File.exists`... but this means hard-coding a path, which sucks, or looking through the configured asset paths.  It seems like this should be there already, but I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Looks like Joe's answer is bang on. You gonna mark it as correct?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Given an image in `app/assets/images/lolshirts/theme/bg-header.png`,

```
Rails.application.assets.find_asset 'lolshirts/theme/bg-header.png'
 => #> Sprockets::StaticAsset:0x80c388ec pathname="/Users/joevandyk/projects/tanga/sites/lolshirts/app/assets/images/lolshirts/theme/bg-header.png", mtime=2011-10-07 12:34:48 -0700, digest="a63cc84aca38e2172ae25de3d837c71a">

Rails.application.assets.find_asset 'notthere.png'
 => nil
```

Comment: Just a note... If you pass a path with a leading slash, you'll get an exception if the asset doesn't exist instead of the nice `nil`

Comment: @dwhite Passing '/notthere.png' still produces a `nil` on Rails 3.2

Comment: This does not seem to work in production https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/476

Comment: This is not working anymore since Rails 4.2 with disabled compile_assets.
Some research shows that this behaviour is intendet and won't be changen probably: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/237

Answer (score 45):

Since this is still the top question when searching Google, and since the accepted answer does not work properly in production (at least in some cases), here is the solution that works for me (Rails 4.x to 6.x at least):

```
def asset_exist?(path)
  if Rails.configuration.assets.compile
    Rails.application.precompiled_assets.include? path
  else
    Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets[path].present?
  end
end
```

This is copied from [this github issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/298#issuecomment-168927471)

Comment: Is there any equivalent of that method using rails 5.2/webpacker?

Comment: does this still work on rails 5 or 6?

Comment: Confirmed still working on at least up to 6.x

Comment: I am very sad. I've used this for years. Today, after moving to propshaft and Rails 7.  In production, not in test,  I get (undefined method `precompiled_assets' for #<Apoxeia::Application>). Probably me somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217598/549252

```
= Rails.application.assets.find_asset("my_asset.css").nil?
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see the answer here for a discussion on why `find_asset` may not always work:

[Include Assets Only If They Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206661/include-assets-only-if-they-exist/22566120#22566120)

Comment: I think this would be better served as a comment on the accepted answer - as it stands, it doesn't answer the question.