# Include Assets Only If They Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In our current rails app, we are following certain patterns for including assets such as scripts and stylesheets.

For instance, one such pattern is (code inside the layout):

```
= stylesheet_link_tag controller.controller_name
```

The problem here is that not *all* of the controllers are going to have associated stylesheets. What is the best way to check if an asset exists? Specifically, I know there is some trickery here due to the cache busting asset names.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally figured this one out. Asset existence can be checked as follows:

```
YourApp::Application.assets.find_asset("#{asset}.css").nil?
```

The answer would then be:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag controller.controller_name if YourApp::Application.assets.find_asset("#{controller.controller_name}.css")
```

Comment: Won't this only work if you have precompile set to true? It'll fail in most production environments.

Comment: One also should be careful, because this will only include *.css files ignoring *.scss and *.sass.

Comment: I would strongly urge the question author to read the answer by @randy below ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22566120/289324)), as it implies that this (the currently accepted) answer will cause real problems in a production environment, namely, always recompiling the asset.

Answer (score 16):

I had found this answer before and we'd been happily using `find_asset` in our application (Rails 3.2.16), until one day it started bombing out.

After some digging, it turns out that even in a production environment, with asset precompilation enabled, the first call to `find_asset` will attempt to actually compile the asset it's looking for, even if that asset has been precompiled already. As you can imagine, this is not good news -- in our specific case, we were pulling in a Compass library file into a stylesheet, which worked in dev and during precompile, but not in production, where Compass was not in the assets load path.

Long story short, `find_asset` is not a bulletproof way to determine if an asset is available to include. You can read a bunch more about it in the issue someone tried to file about this, and which was subsequently closed as not a bug: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/411

The real way to determine if an asset exists, and which works in both compile and precompile modes is demonstrated in the hoops that the filer of the above issues needed to jump through. Here's the diff for his fix: https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails/pull/55/files

I'm putting this here in hopes that other Googlers who find this don't fall into the same trap I did!

Answer (score 2):

To include an asset based on **controller name**

```
<% controller_asset = controller.controller_name %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag controller_asset if YourApp::Application.assets.find_asset(controller_asset) %>
```

To include an asset based on **controller name and action name** (was useful for me)

```
<% action_asset = "#{controller.controller_name}/#{controller.action_name}" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag action_asset if YourApp::Application.assets.find_asset(action_asset) %>
```

And of course it'd be better not to leave this code as it is, but rather place it in a helper.

Answer (score 0):

```
= stylesheet_link_tag controller.controller_name if File.exists?(File.join(Rails.public_path, 'assets', "#{controller.controller_name}.css"))
```

Comment: I haven't tested this code, but at a glance it doesn't seem to take into account the cache busting suffix. E.g. controller-181432da64a0609a7571e391af2c4d6c.css.

Comment: Rails will copy the original files aside with the ones with digest suffix. Maybe you can change `Rails.public_path` to `Rails.root, 'app/assets'`

Comment: I am not seeing the original files aside wit the ones with the digest suffix, but this is in the development environment.

Comment: I am also hesitant to use Rails.root 'app/assets' since I would have to take into account all the different types of assets (sass, scss, css, etc.). There has to be something like asset_exists?

Answer (score 0):

### Simple ViewHelpers

This is what I use myself. Add this to your `ApplicationHelper`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def controller_stylesheet(opts = { media: :all })
    if Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.css")
      stylesheet_link_tag(params[:controller], opts)
    end
  end

  def controller_javascript(opts = {})
    if Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.js")
      javascript_include_tag(params[:controller], opts)
    end
  end
end
```

and use them like this in your `application.html.haml`:

```
= controller_stylesheet
= controller_javascript
```

---

***Note:*** This works with all .js, .coffee, .css, .scss even though it just says .css and .js