# Rails Asset Pipeline - How to determine if an asset exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Is there any way to ask the Asset Pipeline if an asset exists? The suggestions I largely see involve manually checking the file path with `File.exist?`. The problem with that is that I have several gems that include assets, so I would have to look at the assets directories for each of those, right? This seems like something I would expect to be baked into the Asset Pipeline, but I can't find any reference to it.

My current solution is an ugly hack, so I hope you have something better. Calling `asset_path(file)` will either return a new URL (/asset/xyz) for an asset or the same path if it does not exists (or if it's an absolute path). So my ugly hack is:

```
def has_asset?(path)
  # Asset pipeline only does relative paths
  if path[0] == '/'
    return false
  end
  asset_path(path) != '/#{path}'
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just found that I can use `assets.find_asset`:

```
def has_asset?(path)
  Rails.application.assets.find_asset(path) != nil
end
```

Comment: For the sake of googlers landing here - be careful, this does not seem to work properly in production https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/476

Comment: If someone is looking for a solution that works in production, refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35319530/413924)

Comment: this doesn't work when assets are compiled. the answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

The currently accepted answer does not work in production.

I use the following method to work in both development and production environments:

```
module AssetHelper
  def asset_exists?(path)
    if Rails.env.production?  
      Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources(path) != nil
    else
      Rails.application.assets.find_asset(path) != nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources(path)` can't return `nil` (Rails 4 with Sprockets 3). I used `Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources(path).any?`. Thanks for this code!

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with the suggested solutions above sometimes returning true when an asset did not exist this fixes the issue

```
def asset_exists?(path)
  if Rails.env.production?
    all_assets = Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources(path)

    if all_assets
      keys = Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets.keys

      if keys.include?(path)
        true
      else
       false
      end
    else
      false
    end
  else
    Rails.application.assets.find_asset(path) != nil
  end
end
```

Comment: great stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Propshaft in dev you'll want to use:

```rb
Rails.application.assets.load_path.find('path/filename.jpg').present?
```

Not sure about prod.